# WordPress SSL redirects through Cloudflare

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, ssl, redirect

I have added my website to Cloudflare for use of flexible SSL. Everything on static content is ok. For example, I can access my files directly with https (Ex: `https://www.samanik.com/logo.png`).
but I can't access the WordPress site. I have changed both the site_url and home_url in the db. I have added codes to .htaccess, but when I type my website without https it redirects to https (as I want). But, nothing is shown there. I get an error called `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` I don't know how to fix this problem.

Here is my .htaccess content.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redirect to **HTTPS** using action hook as well.

Add the below code in your `**functions.php**`:

```
function redirectToHTTPS(){
 if($_SERVER['HTTPS']!="on"){
   $redirect= "https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    header("Location:$redirect");   
}}
add_action('init','redirectToHTTPS' );
```

For detailed guide, check **[here](http://prabinparajuli.com.np/redirect-to-https-ssl-in-php/)**.

Answer (score 2):

in General Settings set your `WordPress Address (URL)` `Site Address (URL)` to `https://...`

update:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301] 

# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: In addition, if all else fails, something like [this](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/wordpress/wordpress-changing-the-site-url-and-home-settings) is probably what you would want to look at!

Comment: I have changed it from phpmyadmin (because I can't access it through wp-admin panel).
nothing changed

Comment: added `.htaccess` to answer, try it.